# How to count all the same size sequence of repeating value in a column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to transform a column that have several repeating values ​​into a dataframe that has one column for each unique value and the rows count the number of times that a same size repeating sequecence has occurs.

Example: imagine the results of a sport team (win, draw, loss).

```
results = np.array (['w', 'w', 'l', 'l', 'd', 'w', 'l', 'l', 'd', 'd', 'w' , 'w', 'w', 'w', 'l', 'w', 'w', 'd', 'w', 'w', 'l', 'd', 'l'])
```

The question is how many times the team had a single win, two wins in a row, three wins in a row and so on. In other words transform that column in this DataFrame:

```
df_freq = pd.DataFrame ({'w': [1,3,0,1], 'd': [3,2,0,0], 'l': [3,1,0,0]}, index = range (1,5))
```

Note: The sequence only counts for the highest order (a four times repeat doesn't count also as two two times repeat).

I tried to do this with a combination of building-in functions of pandas such as `.groupby` `.transform` `.value_counts`, but only get it using loops and is returning error warning ("A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from the DataFrame ") also NaN instead of zeros.

So the question is how can I improve it for a faster and short code.
The code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

results = np.array(['w','w','l','l','d','w','l','l','d','d','w','w','w','w','l','w','w','d','w','w','l','d','l'])

df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns =['results'])
list_results = df['results'].unique()
df_occ = pd.DataFrame(columns = list_results) 
df['CumCount'] = df.groupby(['results']).cumcount()

for r in list_results:
    df[r] = df['results'].eq(r)
    df['end '+str(r)] = (df[r] == True) & (df[r].shift(-1) == False)
    if (df[r].iloc[-1] == True):
        df['end '+str(r)].iloc[-1] = True
    df_occ[r] = pd.concat([df['CumCount'][df['end '+str(r)] == True].diff().fillna(df['CumCount']+1)], ignore_index = True)

max_occ = int(df_occ.max().max())
df_freq = pd.DataFrame(0 ,columns = list_results, index = np.arange(1, max_occ+1))

for r in list_results:
    values = df_occ[r].value_counts(dropna=True).keys().tolist()
    counts = df_occ[r].value_counts(dropna=True).tolist()
    df_freq[r] = df_freq[r].index.map(dict(zip(values, counts)))
print(df_freq)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this with 2 groupbys. The first groups consecutive events. The second gets the frequency of those.

```
s = pd.Series(results)
df = s.groupby(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()).agg(['size', 'first'])
df.groupby([*df]).size()

#size  first
#1     d        3
#      l        3
#      w        1
#2     d        1
#      l        2
#      w        3
#4     w        1
```

Or reshape if you want and ensure all the possible sizes are displayed:

```
(df.groupby([*df]).size().unstack(-1)
   .reindex(range(1, df['size'].max()+1))
   .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

#        d    l    w
#size               
#1     3.0  3.0  1.0
#2     1.0  2.0  3.0
#3     NaN  NaN  NaN
#4     NaN  NaN  1.0
```

Comment: A nice truly pandas solution :) +1

Comment: Thank you for the answer that was exactly what I was searching for!

Answer (score 2):

You may take advantage of the grouping feature of `itertools.groupby` to construct a list of tuples key-len of each consecutive key. Use it to construct a dataframe, and call `pivot_table` on this dataframe

```
from itertools import groupby

arr = [(k, len(list(g))) for k, g in groupby(results)]
df_final = pd.DataFrame(arr).pivot_table(index=1, columns=0, aggfunc='size')

Out[271]:
0    d    l    w
1
1  3.0  3.0  1.0
2  1.0  2.0  3.0
4  NaN  NaN  1.0
```

---

**Note**: If you want index `3` with all `0` or `NaN`, just chain additional `reindex` as in @ALollz solution. For this step, I would use the same `reindex` as him so I don't write it out.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that is a clever way of doing also. Good to learn some tools out of pandas can do the job.